# Using VBA how can I check two columns using an If / And statement and then highlight based on conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub highlight_2()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E:F")
    For Each cell In R
    
    If Range("E1").Value = "MAKE" Then
        If Range("F1").Value = "Y" Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So what I want is if column E has the word 'make' and column F has the letter 'Y' then highlight. But I want to check both rows completely, or at least 200 rows.

I did it with one like this

```vb
Sub Highlighting_cells()
    
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("E:E")

    For Each cell In R
        If cell.Value = "Make" Then
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through the rows, [there are several questions on this site on doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+loop+through+rows). Side note: is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by [Nomad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8260484/cybernetic-nomad), this can easily be done, using conditional formatting. In my example, I'm using the formula: `=AND($E1="make",$F1="Y")`.

Hereby the corresponding screenshot (as you see, the checks are case insensitive):

[image: screenshot]

For your information: column "G" shows the formula result, it is not needed but when working with conditional formatting based on a formula, I always start by creating such a helper column in order to get the formula right.

Comment: Although it is true, *"as you see, the checks are case insensitive"* would require a different screenshot (all *make*-s are in lowercase).

Comment: @VBasic2008: you're right: my answer is just an example of the principle. By replacing the `=` operator by the `=EXACT()` function, case sensitivity can be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Your can loop over the rows in the range:

```
Sub highlight_2()
    Dim rng As Range, rw as Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = activeSheet 'or some specific sheet
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(ws.Range("E:F"), ws.UsedRange) 'don't process all rows...

    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If rw.cells(1).Value = "MAKE" Then
            If rw.cells(2).Value = "Y" Then
                rw.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```